# black diamond with a white question mark or an empty square box

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

My Input File Having This symbol � & I want to insert this symbolic file into my database by using pdi kettle so please tell me how I can solve this problem

ex
I/p :
Id   F_Name   LName
101  John     Ce�na

O/P Should be the same 
Id   F_Name   LName
101  John     Ce�na

please help me to solve this

Comment: You want to actually read this character ? Your file input is probably using an unspecified character encoding, try changing it to UTF-8 or the one that the file actually is.

Comment: My PDI Kettel Default Encoding is UTF - 8

Comment: Have you tried other Encodings ? Another way to actually what is being inputed in pentaho is to open the text file in another program, i highly suggest Notepad++, has a lot of usability and you can easily swap encondings and do basic debugging.

Answer (score 1):

which database are you trying to populate and what collation properties do you have setup at your end.

also you can try to key in this information by any database client and see if the same is allowed in your column/table structure.